# Midway between combine_first and merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master dataframe A

```
id    A       B       C
0     a       b       c
1     d       e       f
2     g       h       i
3     j       k       l
```

and a newer dataframe B

```
id    A       B       D
0     a2      b2      x 
1     d2      e2      y 
2     g2      h2      z 
3     j2      k2      NaN
4     l2      m2      NaN
5     n2      o2      NaN
```

If I `merge` them, I get duplicated columns like `A`, `A_x`, `B` and `B_x`. If I use `combine_first`, I end up with rows `4`,`5`, and column `D`, which I'm not interested in. Besides doing something like

```
not_on_a = B["id"].isin(A["id"])
B = B.loc[not_on_a, [A,B]]
A = A.combine_first(B)
```

Is there a way to overwrite `B` on `A` ignoring everything that isn't on `A`? The desired output is

```
id    A       B       C
0     a2      b2      c
1     d2      e2      f
2     g2      h2      i
3     j2      k2      l
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the indices are the same, this is a simple [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "d", "g", "j"], "B": ["b", "e", "h", "k"], "C": ["c", "f", "i", "l"]})
>>> df1
   A  B  C
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
2  g  h  i
3  j  k  l
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a2", "d2", "g2", "j2", "l2", "n2"], "B": ["b2", "e2", "h2", "k2", "m2", "o2"], "D": ["x", "y", "z", None, None, None]})
>>> df2
    A   B     D
0  a2  b2     x
1  d2  e2     y
2  g2  h2     z
3  j2  k2  None
4  l2  m2  None
5  n2  o2  None
>>> df1.update(df2)
>>> df1
    A   B  C
0  a2  b2  c
1  d2  e2  f
2  g2  h2  i
3  j2  k2  l
```

If you don't want to mutate the first dataframe, you can make a [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) first.

Comment: nice one. `update` is the way to go. Never used that one.

Comment: didn't know about this one either, thanks a lot. Currently `id` is a column but I can set it as index for this.

Comment: didn't know about this one either, thanks a lot. Currently `id` is a column but I can set it as index for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join` and then clean up the dataframe as desired. I do this dynamically by putting `drop` in the suffix of the columns you later use to `dropna` values by defining the subset of columns as those with "drop" in them.

```
df = B.join(A, lsuffix='', rsuffix='drop')
df = df.dropna(subset=[col for col in df.columns if 'drop' in col])
df = df[A.columns]
df

id    A       B       C
0     a2      b2      c
1     d2      e2      f
2     g2      h2      i
3     j2      k2      l
```